# How can I access url variable from zend view script instead of controller level?

Tags: zend-framework

Example:
    http://domain.local/user/edit/id/23
    controller = user
    action = edit
    id = 23

From controller I can easily get a value of the request variable "id" by writing 
    $id = $this->_getParam('id');

But I want to get it from the view script (user/edit.phtml) directly. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view type

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('id', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it from the controller to the view:-

In your controller:-

```
$this->view->id = $this->_getParam('id');
```

Then in your view it is available with:-

```
$this->id;
```

Comment: Yes that's really easy. But I wanted it directly. Because I am accessing it from some view partials. So in this case I have to pass it to those partials again from the view script. It's a lot of task to manage. If I could get it from the partial itself then it would be great.

Comment: Don't forget that the seperation of view and controller is there for a reason.